# Create NSObject from NSDictionary in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, nsdictionary, nsobject

I would like to assign each item from a dictionary into my object using a "for...in" loop

I have a NSDictionary like that :

```
{"user_id" : "1", "user_name" : "John"}
```

And I have an NSObject with variable :

```
NSString *user_id;
NSString *user_name
```

With a for in loop, I want to assign each item from my NSDictionary in my NSObject

```
for (NSString *param in userDictionary) {

}
```

How I can do that ?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you mean you have an `NSObject` _subclass_ with properties `user_id` and `user_name`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have a look at the NSObject class method:

```
- (void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key;
```

For example:

```
[userDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop){
    [myObject setValue:obj forKey:(NSString *)key];
}];
```

Comment: You can check before `code` if([obj respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(key)])`code`

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small library that automates this, it also handles conversion of dates
https://github.com/aryaxt/OCMapper

It automatically converts NSDictionary to NSObject as long as all keys are the same as property names.

```
Customer *customer = [Customer objectFromDictionary:customerDictionary];
NSArray *customers = [Customer objectFromDictionary:listOfCustomersDictionary];
```

if the key and property names are not the same you can write mapping

```
[mappingProvider mapFromDictionaryKey:@"dob" toPropertyKey:@"dateOfBearth" forClass:[Customer class]];
```

Comment: Awesome library, I used some others like Mantle.. but your is very good, keep updating it. Thank u a lot!